# Can macOS launchd run a bash script?

Tags: bash, launchd

My question title is voluntarily provocative.

'Yes, of course' would be a mac aficionado (like me) first answer.

'It is NOT so obvious' is my auto-reply after three days struggling, searching and sweating in a highly frustrating mood for what i believe should be much and much easier.

My problem:
I wrote a simple bash script to backup some important files on a different
destination. I called that script 'backup'. 
One of the contained commands is as follows:

```
cp "$(latest "Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xyhlne3n.default/bookmarkbackups")" /Users/me/Backup
```

That is evidently a 'Command substitution' in bash speek.
Now, my script itself, which contains more commands, first of all

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

to make every other non-interactive shell be able to recognize 'latest', a function I defined in .bashrc to extract most recently modified file inside a dir, works a charm when run from a shell.
But, I would really be happy if I could have it run on regular basis with launchd, which, I learnt, CANNOT, among other amenities, parse `$VAR`and so it is not able to run the job.

Is there a way to make launchd digest my 'latest' function so defined:

```
    function latest {
unset -v latest;
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        [[ $file -nt $latest ]] && latest=$file
    done
    echo "$latest"
}
```

?

Because, at every load, it results in the same error:

cp: fts_open: No such file or directory.

Thank you

Comment: I can't quite follow your question, but I think you maybe want `export -f latest` after the definition of the function so that sub shells can use it... maybe.

Comment: Are you sure your script is running in bash and not in some other shell (sh, ksh, etc)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, no, unfortunately that does not help.

Comment: @brunorey all my scripts have '#!/usr/local/bin/bash' on top of 'em.

Comment: Are you sure it is running as your user and not as `root` or some system userid? Because the reference to `~` may be a problem, and `$HOME` may be better, or even `/Users/YourUser`.

Comment: Another option may be to make a script called `latest` and store it in `/usr/local/bin` where everyone with the appropriate PATH can use it.